# ul floating over parent div bottom border

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Unordered list is floating over the bottom border of its' parent div. I do not understand why this happens and have only found work-arounds to solve the problem.

[image]

When I increase height of parent div (red border box) the ul will stay in the exact same position.

```css
.bottom-container .comment-list .comment .buttons {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.bottom-container .comment-list .comment .buttons #comment-details {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.bottom-container .comment-list .comment .buttons #comment-details a li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 1.0);
  border-right: 2px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, 1.0);
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <ul id="comment-details">
    <a id="reply-button">
      <li> Reply <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 12pt"> reply </i></li>
    </a>
    <a id="upvote">
      <li> 5 <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 12pt"> arrow_upward </i></li>
    </a>
    <a id="downvote">
      <li> 1 <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 12pt"> arrow_downward </i></li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want the ul to be right in the middle and floating to the right of the parent div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS can be tricky, but I think its cause the padding for the .button class doesn't have the top and bottom set so its default.

Also the margins isn't set for top and bottom for the ul, too so it could throwing it off.

Comment: You were completely right, setting top and bottom margin to 0 on the ul solved the issue. Thanks!